# How to Write Multiline String With Significant Whitespace at the End

Tags: swift4

I’m converting a previously concatenated string to the new [multi-line string syntax](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0168-multi-line-string-literals.md) introduced in Swift 4. It contains signifiant whitespace at the end of lines, so I’m using the [string newline escaping](https://apple.github.io/swift-evolution/) to explicitly terminate the line with `\n\` after the significant whitespace, to protect it from the editor (Xcode) that strips the whitespace from the end of the line.

```swift
let asciiArt = """
 \ /   \n\
  V    \
"""
```

Problem is with the last line, where I don’t want the newline to be part of the string, but cannot use just a single \ because it gives me error:

`Escaped newline at the last line is not allowed`

How do I write multiline string with significant trailing whitespace that doesn’t contain newline at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the error is due to [quirks in Swift parsing grammar](https://forums.swift.org/t/significant-whitespace-at-the-end-of-multiline-string/12675) and the workaround in Swift 4.0 and 4.1 is to insert **extra newline at the end**, to make the compiler happy:

```swift
let asciiArt = """
 \ /   \n\
  V    \

"""
```

Notice the empty line before the closing `"""`!

In Summary: to write a multiline string that ends with significant whitespace and **doesn’t contain** a trailing **newline**, insert **one more newline** at the end. The compiler removes the newlines after the opening `"""`, before the closing `"""` and after every line-trailing `\`, which leaves you with:

- a string that ends in whitespace without `\n`,
- a content compiler and
- a question why people follow made-up rules ad-absurdum like robots... ‍♂️‍♂️